# Optimal way to count big data in pandas

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, pandas, bigdata

I have a dataframe in pandas with 19,000,000 rows. The headers are artist and week. I want to add another column on which I calculate the number of times the artist appears in a given week. Right now I'm using the following code:

```
#Function to determine the number
def playsxweek(week,art):
    return len(data[(data.week == week) & (data.artist == art)])
#Then I map
data['playsxweek'] = map(playsxweek,data['week'],data['artist'])
```

Right now the code takes an eternal time to process all the 19 million records... Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason this is taking for ever isn't because its processing is 19,000,000 times, but three trillion times**.

If there are 3 artists and 52 weeks, thats 3 x 52 x 19,000,000 or 2,964,000,000. **Three trillion searches**, and each new artist would add another 988,000,000. Nearly a trillion searches for each artist!

Instead, iterate through the data once and build a count as you go through (this example assumes each row can be accessed as a dictionary):

```
playsPerWeek=dict()
for row in data:
    week, artist = row['week'],row['artist']
    playsPerWeek[(week, artist)] = playsPerWeek.get((week, artist),0) + 1
```

Here we instantiate a count, and iterate through each row once. Then we use `.get()` to see if the `(week, artist)` tuple exists as a key (if it doesn't use the default value 0), add one and assign it ack into the dictionary.

For reference, since tuples are immutable, they can be used as dictionary keys, whereas lists cannot.

Comment: The only thing is that it throws the error "too many values to unpack"  because of the nature of the data... maybe try iteritems()?

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% down with pandas, so you need to fix the iteration to be more specific. I've made a slight change that may be closer to what you need. But the logic behind why your code was taking so long holds.

Comment: you should look at HYRY soln, will be WAY more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think `groupby` will solve the problem:

```
data.groupby(["week", "artist"]).count()
```